# Can an API be used without HTTP by applications on the same server?

Tags: api, http, cakephp

I am about to build a CRM application in CakePHP. The CRM will require an API for other applications to extract the data. 
Applications that are not on the same server will obviously access this via some sort of API caller object that makes an HTTP request to the CRM.

As I understand it, the HTTP request time will increase to the overall load time. For applications on the same server is it possible/is it common practice to access the API by some other means. i.e. including the controller and using the actions ... (im not even sure if this would work as the framework wouldn't be bootstrapped right?). By doing this I am looking to: 1) Reduce load times. 2) Return data as PHP arrays instead of json/xml objects.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return HTTP responses then you need some kind of HTTP server, API's are designed for exactly the reason that you are describing above - they allow multiple applications to access the data in a database by creating an interface to it in a way that can be controlled and standardised.

If you design your API well, have it return JSON objects then the average response shouldn't be a problem as you will only be returning a small amount of text.

Getting a PHP array from a JSON object is as simple as `json_decode($json_object, true);`

If you are using CakePHP to create an API you should look at using the [awesome CRUD plugin by Friends of Cake](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud)